# Create a relativs list of a page hierarchy in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress I have sorted all pages in a nice hierarchy. Now I want to list the parents, relativs, children and grandchildren to the active page when I visit a page. Not the full site page hierarchy

For exemple my page hierarchy looks like this

*-Parent1

      -Children1-1

      -Children1-2

        -grandchildren1-2-1

        -grandchildren1-2-2

    -Children1-3

    -Children1-4


-Parent2

    -Children2-1

    -Children2-2


-Parent3

    -Children3-1

    -Children3-2

        -grandchildren3-2-1*

So if i visit page "**Children2-1**" i want a list(menu) thats shows only
*-Parent2

    -Children2-1

    -Children2-2*


And if I visit "**grandchildren3-2-1**"
the list(menu) look like

*-Parent3

    -Children3-1

    -Children3-2

        -grandchildren3-2-1*

How can I manage this? ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below working code. It will give you result as you want.

```
$parrent_pgid=$post->post_parent;

$current_pgid=$post->ID;

get_page_template_slug( $current_pgid );

?>

<div class="left_sidebar" id="pg_<?php echo $current_pgid;?>">

<?php

 if ($post->post_parent)    {
 $ancestors=get_post_ancestors($post->ID);
 $root=count($ancestors)-1;
 $parent = $ancestors[$root];
 } else {
 $parent = $post->ID;
 }

 $children = wp_list_pages("sort_column=post_title&title_li=&child_of=". $parent ."&echo=0");

   if ($children) { ?>
  <ul id="subnav">
  <?php echo $children; ?>
  </ul>
  <?php } ?>

 </div>
```